# Apache RewriteRule replace words and remove duplicates

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling to create a RewriteRule that does 2 things :

1. replace some words by others (ex "color_light_blue" and "color_dark_blue" become "color_blue")
2. remove duplicates (if some are created by rule 1)

Here is an example :

> mysite.com/products/brand_1-color_light_blue-color_dark_blue-color_red

should get redirected (301) to

> mysite.com/products/brand_1-color_blue-color_red

using this :

```
    RewriteRule (.*)color_(blue-light|blue-dark|saphir)+(.*) $1color_blue$3
RewriteRule (.*)color_(grey-light|platinium)+(.*) $1color_grey$3 [NC,R=302,L,N=10]
```

seems to work ONLY if all the parameters are met.
The rewriterules doesn't seems to chain.

Comment: What rule have you created so far?

Comment: so far, not much...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/color_blue_light(.*) /$1/color_blue$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/color_blue_dark(.*) /$1/color_blue$2 [R,L]
I tried with the [C], but it doesn't seems to work.
And for now I have no idea on how to replace duplicates.

Comment: I made some progress...
with something like that :
RewriteRule (.*)color_(blue-light|blue-dark|saphir)+(.*) $1color_blue$3
RewriteRule (.*)color_(grey-light|platinium)+(.*) $1color_grey$3 [NC,R=302,L,N=10]
the colors are rewritten.
But the duplicates issue is quite hard...

Comment: Please edit your question. Do not add additional details in comments.